# Mongodb Realm with Expo React-Native

Tags: android, mongodb, react-native, expo, realm

I'm using Mongodb Atlas Realm sync on flexible mode in my expo react-native application, and I'm facing a problem with syncing only when I use Android (with iOS it's working).

My package.json:

```
"@realm/react": "^0.6.0",
"expo": "^49.0.6",
"react-native": "0.72.3",
"react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0",
"realm": "^11.10.2",
...
```

App.js:

```
async function LogIn() {
  const app = new Realm.App({ id: "xxx" });
  await app.logIn(Realm.Credentials.anonymous());
}

function LoadingIndicator(){
  return(
    <AppLoader/>
  )
}
export default function App() {
  return (
    <AppProvider id={"xxx"} baseUrl="https://realm.mongodb.com">
      <UserProvider fallback={LogIn}>
        <RealmProvider schema={[patientTasks]} sync={{ flexible: true }}
 fallback={LoadingIndicator}>
          <AppContextProvider>
            <AuthProvider>
              <Initial /> 
            </AuthProvider>
          </AppContextProvider>
        </RealmProvider>
      </UserProvider>
    </AppProvider>
  )
}
```

first loaded component:

```
const realm = useRealm()
const tasks = useQuery(patientTasks).filtered('caregiver==$0',new BSON.ObjectId(userObjectID));
realm.addListener("change", onRealmChange)

//Here only ios is printed when I change/add/remove something on my DB atlas even though both android emulator and ios are running
function onRealmChange() {
  console.log(Platform.OS)
}
```

I tried to manually change on the android directory but that resulted to many other errors.
Also I can't delete the reanimated package because it's being used on the project.